# Exception actual filename, methodname and line # WPF

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, exception

I am working on a WPF project, where as all my INotify implementation are in base class, when there is an error occurs inside property changed event, I would always get base class as file name and setvalue line # as my exception line #, is there is anyway I can get the actual action or method or property which caused the exception and line # of the same? I guess its tricky.

Note I am able to use StackFrame to get baseclass, method, line # which is not what I am looking for

Comment: how are errors happening in your PC event?

Comment: HOW? NotifyPropertyChanged or OnPropertyChanged should be a 3 line function; it shouldn't be throwing exceptions at all. I suggest you add checks to you properties to prevent exceptions from happening.